# Display dates as actual dates in x-axis of ggplotly plot and not as months only

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have the dataframe below and I want to display the values in the x-axis as actual dates and not as months.

```
Targets2<-structure(list(Week = structure(c(17903, 17903, 17910, 17910, 
17917, 17917, 17924, 17924, 17931, 17931, 17938, 17938, 17945, 
17945, 17952, 17952, 17959, 17959, 17966, 17966, 17973, 17973, 
17980, 17980, 17987, 17987, 17994, 17994, 18001, 18001, 18008, 
18008, 18015, 18015, 18022, 18022, 18029, 18029, 18036, 18036
), class = "Date"), Type = c("Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target", "Target", "Cumilative target", "Target", 
"Cumilative target"), Count = c(5, 5, 8, 13, 15, 28, 20, 48, 
25, 73, 25, 98, 25, 123, 25, 148, 25, 173, 25, 198, 25, 223, 
25, 248, 25, 273, 25, 298, 25, 323, 25, 348, 25, 373, 25, 398, 
25, 423, 25, 448)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))

p <-
    ggplot(Targets2, aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type))+
    geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
    labs(fill = NULL)+
    theme_ipsum() +
    ggtitle("Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment")+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p

# not printed
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in `ggplot` and will be passed on to `plotly`.
You can change the x-axis format with `scale_x_date`. (The labels have been rotated for better readability)

**Code**

```
p <-
  ggplot(Targets2, aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type))+
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week") +
  labs(fill = NULL)+
  ggtitle("Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",,
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

p

ggplotly(p)
```

**Output**
[image]